# ViewModel cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

**Question EDITED**

I am injecting **ViewModelProvider.Factory** to `BaseActivity` like below

```
open class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var factories: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getViewModel(): T {
        return ViewModelProvider(this, factories).get(T::class.java)
    }
}
```

viewModel only works when we inject then like below.

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor( private val alertStore: AlertStore)
    : BaseViewModel(){

    fun showDialog(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(4000)

            alertStore.showToast("Alert after 4 seconds.")
        }
    }
}
```

Why this @Inject constructor is necessary in my current implementation

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

  private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel = getViewModel()
    viewModel.showDialog()
}
```

}

**App.kt**

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().addContext(this).build()
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class,
        ViewModelInjector::class

    ]
)
@Singleton
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun addContext(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideViewModelFactories(viewModels: Map<Class<out ViewModel>,
            @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>):
            ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        return object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                val factory = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() ?: error(
                    "No factory provided against ${modelClass.name}"
                )
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return factory as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ActivityBuilder.kt

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    //@Scope("")
    @ContributesAndroidInjector ///(modules = {MainModelFactory.class})
    public abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();
}
```

**ViewModelInjector.kt**

@Module
public abstract class ViewModelInjector {

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MainViewModel.class)
public abstract ViewModel providesMainViewModel(MainViewModel model);
```

}

**ViewModelKey.kt**

```
@MapKey
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class ViewModelKey(
    val value: KClass<out ViewModel>
)
```

Why do I have to append **@Inject constructor** to each **ViewModel** and kindly explain a little why we need **@Binds @IntoMap** and with ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *dagger android* you should make your activities and fragments as extensions of `DaggerActivity` (and `DaggerFragment` for fragments).

```
class MainActivity : DaggerActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
}
```

Next you should prepare infrastructure for injection:

1. Create injectors for each your activity:

   ```
   // All your injectors can be defined in this module
   @Module(includes = [AndroidInjectionModule::class])
   interface AppInjectorModule {

       @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityVmModule::class, /*other dependecies*/])
       fun getMainActivityInjector(): MainActivity
   }
   ```
2. Create modules to provide view models (can be multiple for one activity) and factory

   ```
   @Module(includes = [VmFactoryModule::class])
   abstract class MainActivityVmModule {

       // bind implementation of ViewModel into map for ViewModelFactory
       @Binds
       @IntoMap
       @ClassKey(MainViewModelImpl::class)
       abstract fun bindMainVm(impl: MainViewModelImpl): ViewModel

       @Module
       companion object {
           @Provides
           @JvmStatic
           fun getMainVm(activity: MainActivity, factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): MainViewModel {
               // create MainViewModelImpl in scope of MainActivity and inject dependecies by ViewModelFactory
               return ViewModelProviders.of(activity, factory)[MainViewModelImpl::class.java]
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Factory can be provided by different module to avoid duplication

   ```
   @Module
   interface VmFactoryModule {

       @Binds
       // bind your implementation of factory
       fun bindVmFactory(impl: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
   }
   ```
3. Add activities injectors to `AppComponent` graph

   ```
   @Component(
       modules = [
           AppInjectorModule::class
       ]
   )
   @Singleton
   interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App>
   ```

Additional info: [Dagger & Android](https://dagger.dev/android)

Comment: kindly explain MainActivityVmModule along with @Binds ,IntoMap and ClassKey . Why we don't use in injecting Activity or fragment whereas we annotate for ViewModel.

Comment: Plz see my updated question which is now working fine. But my concepts are n't clear

Comment: @XarEAhmer when you use `@Binds` approach dagger creates dependencies (Vm) automatically, but you should set annotation `@Inject` on constructor. You should explicitly say dagger which one of constructors it should use to create Vm and inject dependencies. 
You also can create dependency manually by module's method with `@Provides` annotation and set dependencies by setters (not recommended): `@Provides fun getVm(activity: Activity, dependency: VmDependency): ViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity)[MainViewModelImpl::class.java].apply { this.dependency = dependency }`